# Hosting multiple static sites in an s3 bucket and serving them with Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-reverse-proxy, static-site

I have multiple sites that I store in AWS s3, the sites are static and the number of them changes often. Each site is in its own folder and is made out of an index.html file and its CSS and js files.

I'm using Nginx to serve the sites in order for them to be under my domain and it's working (I'm using the confs from here: https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway).

My problem is that I still need to add /index.html at the end of each of my URLs and my customers are not satisfied with it. I would really appreciate any help I'm losing my mind on this problem

Answer (score 2):

A new pull request was made to make it possible:
https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway/pull/42